# Excel Form: Search tool in VBA I cant search a date from a data sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA form in excel in which the user can select a search term like Date and it searches inside the particular date column but I am not able to make it work. For another non-date search term, its works fine. Maybe the date format is the issue I am not sure about it.

[image: Excel Database Sheet]

```vb
Sub Add_SearchColumn()

    frmForm.EnableEvents = False

    With frmForm.cmbSearchColumn
    
        .Clear
        
        .AddItem "All"
        
        .AddItem "Visit Date"
        .AddItem "Visitor Id"
        .AddItem "Visitor Name"
        .AddItem "Patient Name"
        .AddItem "Gender"
        .AddItem "Nationality"
        .AddItem "Time In"
        .AddItem "Time Out"
               
        .Value = "All"
       
    End With
    
    frmForm.EnableEvents = True
    
    frmForm.txtSearch.Value = ""
    frmForm.txtSearch.Enabled = False
    frmForm.cmdSearch.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub SearchData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim shDatabase As Worksheet ' Database sheet
    Dim shSearchData As Worksheet 'SearchData sheet
    
    Dim iColumn As Integer 'To hold the selected column number in Database sheet
    Dim iDatabaseRow As Long 'To store the last non-blank row number available in Database sheet
    Dim iSearchRow As Long 'To hold the last non-blank row number available in SearachData sheet
    
    Dim sColumn As String 'To store the column selection
    Dim sValue As String 'To hold the search text value
    
    
    Set shDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Set shSearchData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SearchData")
    
    
    iDatabaseRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    sColumn = frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value
    
    sValue = frmForm.txtSearch.Value
    
    
    iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:M1"), 0)
    
    'Remove filter from Database worksheet
    
    If shDatabase.FilterMode = True Then
    
        shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    End If

    'Apply filter on Database worksheet
    
    If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "Visitor Id" Then
    
        shDatabase.Range("A1:M" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue
    
    Else
    
        shDatabase.Range("A1:M" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
    
    End If
    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, shDatabase.Range("C:C")) >= 2 Then
    
        'Code to remove the previous data from SearchData worksheet
        
        shSearchData.Cells.Clear
        
        shDatabase.AutoFilter.Range.Copy shSearchData.Range("A1")
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 13
        
        frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30, 60, 80, 40, 60, 80, 65, 60, 65, 60, 60, 60, 70"
        
        If iSearchRow > 1 Then
        
            frmForm.lstDatabase.RowSource = "SearchData!A2:M" & iSearchRow
            
            MsgBox "Records found."
        
        End If
        
        
    Else
    
       MsgBox "No record found."
    
    End If

    shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the wildcards for the date columns, so maybe like the "Visitor ID"  https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-dates.htm

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by taking some hints from the contributer and here is the solution

```
sValue = frmForm.txtSearch.Value

 'My code below to check if the search value is date
If IsDate(sValue) Then
    'do nothing
Else
sValue = Format(frmForm.txtSearch.Value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Date has string format on the sheet. Try to convert it to date before search. If it will not convert properly you canfix it with this trick:

```vba
.Range("Range with date").Value = .Range("Range with date").Value
```